# How to combine multiple rows into one in hibernate3

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

In my project i have to store the timesheet entry in date manner.but display that in week manner.
For example i have a below table

```
Id projectId activityId     Date       Spenttime
1     1       1          2014-11-10     8  
2     1       1          2014-11-11     8  
3     1       1          2014-11-12     8  
4     1       1          2014-11-13     8  
5     1       1          2014-11-14     8  
6     1       1          2014-11-15     8  
7     1       1          2014-11-16     8  
8     1       2          2014-11-10     8  
9     1       2          2014-11-11     8  
10    1       2          2014-11-12     8  
11    1       2          2014-11-13     8  
12    1       2          2014-11-14     8  
13    1       2          2014-11-15     8  
14    1       2          2014-11-16     8
15    2       1          2014-11-15     8
16    2       1          2014-11-16     8
```

I want the result for the above table like this

```
projectId activityId 2014-11-10  2014-11-11 2014-11-12 2014-11-13 2014-11-14 2014-11-15 2014-11-16 
 1           1          8             8         8          8         8          8          8
 1           2          8             8         8          8         8          8          8
 2           1          0             0         0          0         0          8          8
```

Below is the hibernate criteria for getting the above result.

```
List<Timesheet> timesheetList=sessionfactory.getCurrentSession.createCriteria(Timesheet.class)
                              .add(Restrctions.between("date",formatter.parse("2014-11-09"),formatter.parse("2014-11-16"))
                              .list();
```

Retrieve logic:

```
List<DisplayTable> dispaly=new ArrayList<DisplayTable>();
for(int i=0;i<timesheetList.size();i+=7)
{
DisplayTable disp=new DisplayTable();
disp.setProjectId(timesheetList.get(i).getProjectId());
disp.setActivityId(timesheetList.get(i).getActivityId());
disp.setSpentTimeDate1(timesheetList.get(i).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate2(timesheetList.get(i+1).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate3(timesheetList.get(i+2).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate4(timesheetList.get(i+3).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate5(timesheetList.get(i+4).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate6(timesheetList.get(i+5).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate7(timesheetList.get(i+6).getSpentTime());
}
```

The above logic works fine in first two iteration.after that it throws index outofbound exception. i know the exception is throwed because project 2 contains only 2 rows.

Is their any ways to achive the desired result in hibernate3? Any help wll be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more a data design issue than Hibernate. What you seem to need is an entity (table) with following keys:

- projectId
- activityId
- date

And the value will be how many hours worked.

You can then iterate project / activity / date and build a matrix like above

Comment: ,Sorry i already have an entity like your answer.i forgot to  add that in my question.please see the edited question

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a order by projectId, activityId and Date. after retrieving the list loop through until you encounter next activityId (till then add to same object) after which add to a new object and in between add the dates to a List inside the object so that you can iterate it do display in UI. Apply same logic for projectId as well.

```
List<DisplayTable> display = new ArrayList<DisplayTable>();
DisplayTable disp=new DisplayTable();
List<String> timeSheetHours = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i< timesheetList.size(); i+=7) {
    TimeSheet timeSheet = timesheetList.get(i); 
    disp.setProjectId(timeSheet.getProjectId());
    disp.setActivityId(timeSheet.getActivityId());
    // Add timesheet hours to the list
    timeSheetHours.add(timeSheet.getSpentTime());
    //TODO: check if the next record is different activity id,  
    if(true) {
        disp.setTimeSheetHours(timeSheetHoursList);
        display.add(disp);
        disp=new DisplayTable();
        timeSheetHours = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to build your expecting table at Java Side not by Hibernate.

```
List<Timesheet> timesheetList = <Your Method>
```

and **filter** that result by **Project** and **date**.
or either you can make one **Converter** which will return row which you are expecting

And I don't think so your criteria Query will return above second table result what you are expecting.